# Recursive Call Performance

Tags: java, performance, recursion, data-structures

A Job is defined as below:

```
class Job<T> {
  String Class<T> type;

  T execute() throws Exception {
    return type.newInstance();
  }

  static <T> T execute(Job<T> aJob, Job<T>... jobs) {
    //... some lines of unrelated code...
    try{        
      return aJob.execute();
    } catch(Exception e){
      if(jobs.length == 0) throw new RuntimeException(e);
      return execute(jobs[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(jobs, 1, jobs.length));
    }
  }
}
```

> The recursion is needed to reuse the try-catch block. If one job
>   fails, I call the next job. When none of the jobs is succesful, I throw a RuntimeException wrapping the actual Exception. This is merely a fallback mechanism. The code is not the same as mine, but it has the same structure.

What bugs me is the recursive call to execute:

```
execute(jobs[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(jobs, 1, jobs.length));
```

I could have also used a Queue instead of an array:

```
T execute(Job<T> aJob, Queue<Job<T>> jobQueue) {  
//...
execute(jobQueue.poll(), jobQueue);
//...
```

I thought using an array would yield better performance. But using a queue makes the code more readable and intuitive. I haven't tested performance of either option though.

1. What kind of data structure would give better performance?
2. Is there a better way to make this recursive call?
3. Would it be better to use a for loop instead of recursion?

Thanks

Comment: Your `reduce` is just a for-loop, calculate value for every `job` then doing something with them (like you sum or product...) right? Need actual intended code.

Comment: How the values are aggregated? I just see you continuously executeJob and return any value which is not null without aggregation

Comment: I edited the code, and I admit 'reduce' was just a poor choice of word. @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: See my answer. Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you don't want to repeatedly copy over and over, since you're operating on just one array only.

```
static <T> T execute(Job<T> aJob, int begin, Jobs[] jobs) {
    //... some lines of unrelated code...
    try{        
      return aJob.execute();
    } catch(Exception e){

      // if(jobs.length == 0) throw new RuntimeException(e);
      // The condition changed to begin < jobs.length

      if (begin == jobs.length) throws ... // End of array already

      return execute(jobs[0], begin + 1, jobs); // Advance to the next index. No need to copy the array
    }
}
```

We just operate on single array, no need to copy.